# Two dependent random variables from standard normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Problem about finding *two dependent random variables* from **standard** normal distribution. 
For example, I have random variables X1∼N(0, 0.5), X2∼N(0, 0.5). Then I thought that Y1=(X1+X2)∼N(0,1), Y2=(X1-X2)∼N(0,1). But problem is that Y1 and Y2 are **independent** random variables.

Comment: Please clarify your question; currently it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is actually Y1=(X1+X2) and Y2=(X1-X2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy one: let $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim B(1, 1/2)$, a Bernouilli distribution.

Now, let $X_2=X_1 \cdot (-1)^Y$.

That is, you change the sign of $X_1$ randomly. And they must be dependent since $|X_1|=|X_2|$.

Of course, you could simply do $X_2=-X_1$: they are certainly both normal, and dependent, but it's not as fun.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't even thought about the last one!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct two dependent standard normals, the easiest way is probaly to choose your favorite number $\rho\in(0,1)$ and set
$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1&\rho\\ \rho&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the marginal distributions of the bivariate normal $\mathbf{X}=N(0,\Sigma)$ will be two dependent standard normals.